# Вставка большого количества строк в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Вставляю рандомные данные циклом через PHP, но скорость при такой вставке 500-1000 строк в минуту.

Как можно ускорить заполнение таблицы?

Comment: А вы пользуетесь подготавливаемыми запросами ? Т.е. текст запроса компилите один раз и потом многократно выполняете ?

Comment: Зачем использовать PHP для вставки миллиона строк?

Comment: напишите как именно происходит вставка

Answer (score 2):

> **Некоторые способы ускорения вставки:**
>
> Если с одного клиента одновременно вставляется большое количество
>   строк, используйте операторы INSERT в форме, содержащей множество
>   записей. При этом вставка будет происходить намного быстрее (в
>   некоторых случаях в несколько раз), чем при использовании отдельных
>   операторов INSERT. При добавлении данных в непустую таблицу можно
>   настроить переменную myisam_bulk_insert_tree_size так, чтобы это
>   делалось еще быстрее. See section 4.5.6.4 SHOW VARIABLES.
>
> При вставке нескольких строк с различных клиентов можно повысить
>   скорость, используя оператор INSERT DELAYED. See section 6.4.3
>   Синтаксис оператора INSERT.  Обратите внимание: при использовании
>   таблиц MyISAM можно вставлять строки во время выполнения операторов
>   SELECT, если в таблицах нет удаленных строк.  При загрузке таблицы из
>   текстового файла используйте команду LOAD DATA INFILE. При этом обычно
>   вставка будет происходить в 20 раз быстрее, чем при использовании
>   соответствующего количества операторов INSERT. See section 6.4.9
>   Синтаксис оператора LOAD DATA INFILE.
>
> Если таблица имеет много индексов, можно проделать некоторую
>   дополнительную работу, чтобы команда LOAD DATA INFILE выполнялась еще
>   быстрее. Используйте следующую процедуру:
>
> 1. При необходимости создайте таблицу при помощи оператора CREATE TABLE (например, используя mysql или Perl-DBI).
> 2. Выполните оператор FLUSH TABLES или команду оболочки: mysqladmin flush-tables.
> 3. Используйте myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq /path/to/db/tbl_name. После этого индексы не будут использоваться для данной таблицы.
> 4. Вставьте данные в таблицу при помощи LOAD DATA INFILE. При этом никакие индексы обновляться не будут и, следовательно, скорость будет
>      высокой весьма.
> 5. Если вы собираетесь в будущем только лишь читать таблицу, выполните myisampack для этой таблицы, чтобы уменьшить ее размер. See section
>      4.7.4 myisampack, MySQL-генератор сжатых таблиц (только для чтения).
> 6. Воссоздайте индексы при помощи команды myisamchk -r -q /path/to/db/tbl_name. Эта процедура создает индексное дерево в памяти,
>      перед тем как записать его на диск, что гораздо быстрее за счет
>      исключения большого количества дисковых операций. Индексное дерево,
>      получившееся в результате, к тому же отлично сбалансировано.
> 7. Выполните оператор FLUSH TABLES или команду оболочки: mysqladmin flush-tables.  Обратите внимание: команда LOAD DATA INFILE также
>      выполняет вышеупомянутую оптимизацию при вставках в пустую таблицу.
>      Главное отличие этой команды от вышеупомянутой процедуры заключается в
>      том, что при помощи myisamchk можно выделить намного больше временной
>      памяти для создания индекса, чем MySQL, по вашему мнению, должен
>      выделять для каждого воссоздания индексов. Начиная с MySQL 4.0 можно
>      также использовать команду ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS вместо
>      myisamchk --keys-used=0 -rq /path/to/db/tbl_name и ALTER TABLE
>      tbl_name ENABLE KEYS вместо myisamchk -r -q /path/to/db/tbl_name.
>      Таким образом можно также пропускать шаги FLUSH TABLES.   Можно
>      ускорять операции вставки, выполняемые несколькими операторами, путем
>      установки блокировки таблиц:
>
>    mysql> LOCK TABLES a WRITE;
>      mysql> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);
>      mysql> INSERT INTO a VALUES (8,26),(6,29);
>      mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> Главный фактор, влияющий на скорость, - то, что буфер индексов
>   сбрасывается на диск только один раз, после завершения всех операторов
>   INSERT. Обычно содержимое индексных буферов сбрасывалось бы на диск
>   столько раз, сколько имеется различных операторов INSERT. Блокировка
>   не нужна, если можно вставить все строки при помощи одного оператора.
>   Для транзакционных таблиц, чтобы повысить скорость, следует
>   использовать BEGIN/COMMIT вместо LOCK TABLES. Блокировка также понизит
>   полное время проверки подсоединений (multi-connection tests), но
>   максимальное время ожидания для некоторых потоков повысится (потому
>   что они ожидают снятия блокировки). Например:
>
> ```
> поток 1 делает 1000 вставок
> потоки 2, 3 и 4 делают 1 вставку
> поток 5 делает 1000 вставок
> ```
>
> Если блокировка не используется, 2, 3, и 4 завершат выполнение раньше,
>   чем 1 и 5. Если блокировка используется, 2, 3 и 4, видимо, не закончат
>   выполнение раньше, чем 1 или 5, но общее время должно приблизительно
>   уменьшиться на 40%. Так как в MySQL операции INSERT, UPDATE и DELETE
>   очень быстрые, общая производительность будет улучшаться, если
>   добавлять блокировки ко всем командам, делающим более 5 вставок или
>   обновлений подряд. Если делается очень много вставок строк, можно
>   время от времени сопровождать команду LOCK TABLES командой UNLOCK
>   TABLES (после каждых 1000 строк), чтобы позволить другим потокам
>   обращаться к таблице. Результатом всего этого будет получение хорошей
>   производительности. Конечно, для загрузки данных намного более быстрой
>   является команда LOAD DATA INFILE.

[Источник Mysql.ru](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Insert_speed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать как:

```
insert into test_table
select '123', '222'
union
select '333', '111'
union
select '332', '232'
union
...
```

Использовал такой трюк с макросом `vba` для вставки большой таблицы в таблицу Oracle. Сгруппируйте по несколько десятков/сотен тысяч строк в `union` и делайте `insert`.

Comment: В Mysql проще синтаксис: `insert into table values(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)`